# Fragen zu Eingabemethode on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Sind Fragen zur Eingabe deutscher Sprache am PC / Telefon bei uns richtig oder sollten wir auf eine andere Seite verweisen?

Anlass ist diese Frage: [How to write german Um-laut Ä ä Ö ö Ü ü and ß from a non German keyboard?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53471/how-to-write-german-um-laut-%c3%84-%c3%a4-%c3%96-%c3%b6-%c3%9c-%c3%bc-and-%c3%9f-from-a-non-german-keyboard)

Ich frage dies, weil es keine tags mit Technikbezug (im genannten Sinne) gibt, etwa *keyboard* / *Tastatur*, *ime* / *Eingabemethode* oder ähnliches.

Ich möchte hier auch nicht dafür oder dagegen plädieren: einerseits, weil die Anzahl solcher Fragen verschwindend gering ist, andererseits, weil es gute Argumente für beide Positionen gibt.

Answer (score 4):

Fragen um Eingabemethode gehören zu den Seiten, die sich um die Systeme kümmern, anhand derer es eingetippt wird. Nämlich: askubuntu, android, TeX, usw.

Daher plädiere ich für off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Da dies eine Technikfrage und keine Frage zur deutschen Sprache ist, würde ich diese in einem anderen Bereich von SE stellen. GermanSE ist kein Support auf Deutsch, sondern betrifft Fragen u.a. zur Grammatik, Orthographie, Etymologie und Geschichte der deutschen Sprache.

Comment: Haste Recht, danke fürs aufmerksam Machen